# Phonegap 3.0 build error for Android on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I installed the new PhoneGap 3.0 CLI tool on Windows 7 and can create the sample app using:

```
$ phonegap create hello com.example.helloworld HelloWorld
```

But this produces an error:

```
$ phonegap build android
```

Here is the error:

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: read ENOTCONN
```

What do I have to do to get the app to build successfully?

Comment: Please run with `-d` to output more verbose logging, for example, `phonegap create -d hello com.example.helloworld HelloWorld` and post the log here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was using a Cygwin command line interface, and it prepends its own path to a specified file path.

Executing the commands in the standard Windows Command Prompt worked fine.